# Internal Server Error Codeigniter Ajax Uploading File

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am able to send data via ajax, but the server returns error: 500 POST sing_in.

I thought the problem was configuration:
`$config["upload_path"]  = './uploaded_files';` but not.

What do you think is the problem here, because I don't have any idea!!!

Controller:

```
public function sing_in(){

            echo $_FILES['foto_user']['name'];

            $config["upload_path"]   = './uploaded_files';
            $config["allowed_types"] = 'gif|jpg|png';


            $this->load->library("upload",$config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('foto_user')){

                echo  "upload";

            }else{
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }


        }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var url ='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/inicio/sing_in";?>';


    $('#sing_form').on("submit",function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
            //console.log("submited");


                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache:false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                    },error:function(data){
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                });

    });     


});
```

my view:

```
/**
*TABLE SING IN
**/
$this->table->set_heading("","Sing in");
$this->table->add_row(form_label("Username: "),form_input('name_user'));
$this->table->add_row(form_label("Password: "),form_password("password_user"));
$this->table->add_row(form_label("Repeat Password: "),form_password("rpassword_user"));
$this->table->add_row(form_label("Department"),generate_dropdown("department",$departments_results));
$this->table->add_row(form_label('Foto'),form_upload("foto_user"));
$this->table->add_row("",form_submit("sing_in","Sing in"));

echo '<div id="container_table_sign">';
echo form_open_multipart("",'id="sing_form"','name="sing_form"','method="POST"');
echo $this->table->generate();
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Can you post error logs ?

Comment: the error only prints an object with diferents headers but doest say nothing,